# Discord.js | How do I make my bot send a random image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have tried a bunch of things that I've seen and none of them seem to be working for me. I am using the thing where when you do a command it activates a file in the commands folder, and most of the other scripts dont use that.

[image: 1]

Comment: uh, sorry about the image description here, im new to this ;)

Comment: Use `.json` that storage alot of images

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, it is quite difficult to point you in the right direction. It would help more to define the issue you are having (actual errors and/or functionality) along with seeing the code you are using. The solution also depends on where the images are coming from.

Assuming your images are in a local folder, here is a basic example:

```
if (message.content === '!random') {
    // get a random index between 0 and length
    const idx = (len) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (len));

    // get all the files in the directory
    const files = fs.readdirSync('/images/');

    // get file from directory
    const myImage = files[idx(files.length)];
    
    // send image to channel
    message.channel.send({ files: [`/images/${myImage}`] });
}
```

Assuming images are from https://picsum.photos/, here is an basic example:

```
if (message.content === '!random') {
    const seed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    const h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 100;
    const w = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 100;
    
    // create embed with random image
    const embed = new MessageEmbed().setImage(`https://picsum.photos/seed/${seed}/${h}/${w}`);
    
    // send embed
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

    // delete command
    message.delete();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the images from dogpile / an image website. I have tryed a lot of code and none of them seem to be working. I don't get any error, It just doesnt work. I am using brave not chrome and it says it gets the pictures using chrome so I am not sure if that helps?

Comment: Well, that may be part of your difficulty as Dogpile doesn't seem to provide an API, so I assume you are trying to scrape an image from the HTML or something?? I will update my answer to include a different site for pulling random images.

Comment: That works! but now it is sending the same image each time. Any way to make it send a different image each time I type the command?

Comment: I noticed the same thing actually. Something with the way unsplash serves images. Although picsum does the same, but I figured it out. I updated my answer again.

Comment: No problem. Can you mark the answer as correct if it did work as you expected? Thanks!